# porting a dequeue - add loop from C# to F#

Tags: c#, f#

I am trying to port this simple loop:

```
    var messages = new List<string>();
    while (_MessageQueue.TryDequeue(out var message))
        messages.Add(message);
```

where the message queue is concurrent. It is used in a module that enqueues messages from several threads and they are then processed by a single thread.

Is there an idiomatic F# way to do the dequeue / add loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

F# has a couple of ways of doing concurrency including a nice support for [agent-based programming](https://www.developerfusion.com/article/139804/an-introduction-to-f-agents/), so it is quite possible that the idiomatic F# version of what you are doing would not actually use conrrent queues, but would be instead based on agents or some other architecture.

However, to answer your specific question about looping - the C# version is quite terse thanks to the clever use of `while` and `out var`. In F#, you can call `TryDequeue` as a method that returns `bool` together with the value (so we can avoid mutation). I would use that, together with a recursive sequence expression:

```
let mq = System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue<int>()

let rec readAll () = seq {
  let succ, msg = mq.TryDequeue() 
  if succ then
      yield msg
      yield! readAll() }

let messages = readAll() |> List.ofSeq
```

The `readAll` function defines a sequence (`IEnumerable`) that calls `TryDequeue` and if the operation succeeds, it adds the message to the result using `yield msg` and then recursively tries to read more messages by using `yield!`.

Comment: thanks for the answer; I understand everything but the yield! (vs. yield). Can you expand on that?

Comment: Hi, 'yield!' flattens the output, is like an inbuilt fold/reduce,   yielding  "readAll()" without the '!',  would change the return type to "int list list" instead of "int list" and previous "yield msg" would've need to change to "yield [msg]" to satisfy the return type, .... yield! kept the list "flat"

Answer (score 3):

Here's a straight conversion:

```
    open System.Collections.Concurrent

    let _MessageQueue = ConcurrentQueue<string>()
    let messages = ResizeArray<string>()
    let mutable continueLooping = true
    while continueLooping do
        let success, message = _MessageQueue.TryDequeue()
        if success then messages.Add(message)
        continueLooping <- success
```

Comment: yes, it is; thanks for your answer, it is a straight c#->f# port, but I was looking for something idiomatic; I'm learning f# so I'm always looking for new constructs to learn something from.

Answer (score 2):

While this question already has an accepted answer, I wanted to contribute an alternative implementation using the library function `Seq.unfold`:

```
let getAllMessages (mq : _ ConcurrentQueue) =
    mq |> Seq.unfold (fun q ->
        match q.TryDequeue () with
        | true, m -> Some (m, q)
        | _ -> None)

let messages = getAllMessages _MessageQueue |> Seq.toList
```

Not sure if internally it is as complex as (or even more than) Tomas's solution but I find it is short, understandable, and elegant.

Comment: In principle I agree that this is elegant, but it could be simpler, since you do not need to pass any meaningful state to the next iteration. What if you replace the body of your function with `Seq.unfold (fun () -> match mq.TryDequeue() with true, m -> Some (m, ()) | _ -> None) ()`?

Comment: @kaefer I don't see any meaningful difference here. I passed the queue to the lambda to avoid the closure depending on external data.

Answer (score 1):

I'm providing a couple additional design options for giggles. The common parts:

```
open System.Collections.Concurrent

type Message = { I: int }

let queue = ConcurrentQueue<Message>()
```

`drain1` invokes queue.GetEnumerator(), which has the condition that it's returning a snapshot at the time of the initial request. The snapshot is, substantially, the same race condition in the C# version.

```
let drain1 () = queue |> Seq.toList
```

`drain2` returns an array instead, again a snapshot at the time of the initial request. In case you have the luxury of changing the return type.

```
let drain2 () = queue.ToArray()
```

This is an example of the idiomatic return from TryQueue, it avoids an 'out' arg, therefore it's not a mutable value as C# does/did it.

```
let example () =
    let (success, message) = queue.TryDequeue()
    () // ...
```

Finally, a recursively built, self-terminating sequence.

```
let drain3 () =

    let rec drain () = seq {
        let success, message = queue.TryDequeue()
        if success then
            yield message
            yield! drain()
        }

    drain() |> Seq.toList
```

(Standard Internet warranty applies.)

Answer (score 0):

Riffing on [@Scott Hutchinson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58985157/11635)

I'd define an efficient, straightforward helper that encapsulates the mutation and looping :-

```fs
[<AutoOpen>]
module ConcurrentQueueExtensions =
    type System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue<'T> with
        member this.Drain() =
            let buffer = ResizeArray(this.Count)
            let mutable more = true
            while more do
                match this.TryDequeue() with
                | true, req -> buffer.Add req
                | false, _ -> more <- false
            buffer.ToArray()
```

or even leave that generic helper in C#:

```
class ConcurrentQueueExtensions
{
    public static T[] Drain<T>(this System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue<T> that)
    {
        var buffer = new List<T>(that.Count);
        while (that.TryDequeue(out var req))
            buffer.Add(req);
        return buffer.ToArray();
    }
}
```

and then apply it with no mixing of paradigms:

```
let messages = queue.Drain()
```